# Dynamic table added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In the following code, it basically adds a new table dynamically even though it works fine, i have an issue with the width of the column having the content "+" not to auto increase width of this column. I dont mind if the other columns width inceases but the "+" content td should remain constant.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <style>
.table_main {
        border-top-style: ridge;
        border-bottom-style: ridge;
        border-left-style: ridge;
        border-right-style: ridge;
        border-color: red;
        border-width: 3px;
      }

.table_main td {
    background: #A38055;    
    border-right: solid 1px white ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}

.table_main th {
    background: #DCDCDC;
    border-right: solid 1px white ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}

  </style>

</head>
<body>
<table class="table_main">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>Big</td>
            <td width="5%">
            Sl
            </td>
            <td>
            Label 1
            </td>
            <td>
            Label 1
            </td>
            <td>
            Label 1
            </td>
            <td>
            Label 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
        <td rowspan="5">
        Data1:<b/>

        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%"></td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rowId">
            <td width="5%"  onclick="loadSubData()">+</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%"></td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%"></td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
            <td>Some data1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadSubData(){
if($('#dataNode').length <= 0){
$('#rowId').after('<tr id="dataNode"><td width="5%;">h</td><td colspan="4"><table class="table_main">   <tbody>         <tr>        <td>Big</td>            <td width="5%">             Sl          </td>           <td>            Label 1             </td>           <td>            Label 1             </td>           <td>            Label 1             </td>           <td>            Label 1             </td>       </tr>       <tr >       <td rowspan="5">        Data1:<b/>              </td>       </tr>       <tr>            <td width="5%"></td>            <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>         </tr>       <tr id="rowId">             <td width="5%"  onclick="loadSubDatalevel()">+</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>         </tr>       <tr>            <td width="5%"></td>            <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>         </tr>       <tr>            <td width="5%"></td>            <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>         </tr>   </tbody> <table></td></tr>');
}
}
function loadSubDatalevel(){
if($('#dataNode2').length <= 0){
$('#rowId').after('<tr id="dataNode2"><td width="5%;">h</td><td colspan="4"><table class="table_main">  <tbody>         <tr>        <td>Big</td>            <td width="5%">             Sl          </td>           <td>            Label 1             </td>           <td>            Label 1             </td>           <td>            Label 1             </td>           <td>            Label 1             </td>       </tr>       <tr >       <td rowspan="5">        Data1:<b/>              </td>       </tr>       <tr>            <td width="5%"></td>            <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>         </tr>       <tr id="rowId">             <td width="5%"  onclick="loadSubDatalevel()">+</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>         </tr>       <tr>            <td width="5%"></td>            <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>         </tr>       <tr>            <td width="5%"></td>            <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>             <td>Some data1</td>         </tr>   </tbody> <table></td></tr>');
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page. Also when you insert row you aren't adjusting the `rowspan` of first `td`. I believe the `rowspan` issue is what is causing you problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column containing the "+" is wider after the insertion, because the inserted lines at the bottom contains "*Some data1*" in the column whose header is "Sl" (the second column, and not the third).

The problem is that, on the second row of your initial table, you have a `<td rowspan="5">`, but after the insertion, you have a new line, and so you need to update the `rowspan` attribute to 6. You can do this with :

```
$('.table_main tr:nth-child(2) td').attr('rowspan', $('.table_main tr:nth-child(2) td').attr('rowspan')+1);
```